# Setting connection properties (application_name) for Postgres connections

Tags: postgresql, connectivity

I want to attach an application name to my connection like PgAdmin does here:
[image: application_name for pgAdmin]

(Query in text form: `select pid,query,wait_event,state,* from pg_stat_activity;`)

My connections are created this way (here in VBA):

```
Dim cnDB As New ADODB.Connection
cnDB.Open "PostgreSQLDsnHere"
```

Where that DSN is created by:

- for 32 bit: go here: `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`
- for 64 bit: go here: `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe`
- Go to the System DSN tab and enter the information (Data Source,
  Database,Server IP, User Name, Password, Port)

I could not figure out how to add the `application_name` in this context/connection setup (using a DSN).

I tried adding this in various places in my VBA code, but it didn't work:

```
cnDB.Properties("ApplicationName") = "testing"
```

Where do I enter/set the `application_name`?

I know I can set the setting if I use a standard plain text connection string, but I cannot do that for security reasons. I have to use a DSN.

Non-VBA answers very welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't configure it via the DSN itself, you can always have your connection establishing subroutine set the application name by executing a SQL command on the connection before it hands that connection back to the caller:

```
set application_name to 'my application name';
```

In VBScript, this looks like

```
dim cn 
set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=PostgreSQL35WDsnHere" 
cn.open 
cn.execute("set application_name to 'my_application_name';")
```